# asp.net mvc on asp.net 2.0 + ajax extensions 1.0 + iis 6 on win 2k3 server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, iis-6, url-rewriting

I have a lot of problems with url rewrite and ajax extensions 1.0 on a asp.net 2.0 web application.

I am considering using asp.net mvc.

Does it work for me since i am using asp.net 2.0, ajax extensions 1.0 + ajax control toolkit, iis 6 on a win2k3 server?

My development machine is windows vista with iis 7

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

mvc needs the 3.5 framework
"ASP.NET MVC 1.0 provides a new Model-View-Controller (MVC) framework on top of the existing ASP.NET 3.5 runtime."

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

In the blog http://alejandrovidalquiroga.blogspot.com/ there is an partial implementation of ASP.NET MVC for ASP.NET 2.0.